# Foreign key is not assigned to a model in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-database

I recently started learning django and was making a CRM.

***models.py:***

```
class Complaint(models.Model):

SOURCE_CHOICES=(
    ('email','E-mail'),
    ('call','Call'),
    ('ticket','Ticket')
)

store_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
store_contact_no=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
store_id=models.CharField(max_length=7)
source=models.CharField(choices=SOURCE_CHOICES, max_length=10)
agent=models.ForeignKey("Agent", null = True, blank = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
category=models.ForeignKey("Category", related_name="complaints", null = True, blank = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
description = models.TextField()
customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", null = True, blank = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.store_name} {self.store_id}"


class Customer(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

***forms.py***

```
class CustomerComplaintForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Complaint
        fields = (
            'store_name',
            'store_id',
            'store_contact_no',
            'description',  
        )
```

***views.py***

```
class 
CustomerComplaintCreateView(OwnerCustomerAndLoginRequiredMixin, 
generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "customercomplaint_create.html"
    form_class = CustomerComplaintForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return "/complaints"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        complaint = form.save(commit=False)
        complaint.Customer = self.request.user.username
        complaint.source = 'ticket'
        complaint.save()
        return super(CustomerComplaintCreateView, 
    self).form_valid(form)
```

***html template:***

```
{% extends "base.html" %}    
{% load tailwind_filters %}

{% block content %}

<div class="max-w-lg mx-auto">
    <a class="hover:text-blue-500" href="/complaints">Go back to complaints </a>  
    <div class="py-5 border-t border-gray-200">       
    <h1 class="text-4xl text-gray-800"> Create a new complaint  </h1>  
    </div>
    <form method='post' class="mt-5">  
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }} 
        <button type="submit" class="w-full bg-blue-500 text-white hover:bg-blue-600 px- 
        3 py-2 rounded-md">Create</button>
    </form>
</div>                

{% endblock content %}
```

***mixins.py***

```
class OwnerCustomerAndLoginRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):
"""Verify that the current user is authenticated and is an owner or customer"""

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated or not request.user.is_owner and not request.user.is_customer:
        return redirect("/complaints")
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problem here is that, the source field gets filled in the database with Ticket as intended. But the 'Customer' field is not populated with the username. 'Self.request.user.username' is not the problem here as the username is being printed correctly in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `complaint.Customer = self.request.user.username`, you're trying to assign a username to a supposedly `Customer` object. Here's an approach you could take to solve the issue though.

Within the `views.py` file, the view class.

You could get the `customer` object and then assign it to the `customer` field on the `complaint` object.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def form_valid(self, form):
    complaint = form.save(commit=False)
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, user=self.request.user)  # recommended

    # or 
    # customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, user__username__iexact=self.request.user.username)

    if customer:
         # Here on your model you have a lowercase `c` for the customer field, not 'C`
         complaint.customer = customer  # -> This will assign the customer object, "FK".

    complaint.source = 'ticket'
    complaint.save()
    return super(CustomerComplaintCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

That should work.

Comment: oh my god, thank you very much man, this works. It clicked after you said that I was trying to assign a username to the customer model which doesn't have the field by itself.  Thanks for taking the time. :)

Comment: It happens to most of us if not all. That's why we have this wonderful community to help each other. :-)

Answer (score 0):

this must be the User not the user name
Because Cutomer is User object not only the Uesrname

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
        complaint = form.save(commit=False)
        complaint.Customer = self.request.user
        complaint.source = 'ticket'
        complaint.save()
```

Comment: I tried this but it still won't reflect in the database.

Comment: do you run ```manage makemigrations``` and ```migrate```

Comment: Yes I did run them

Comment: are you sure you added all details, maybe there is something you missed?

Comment: also, check if the user does not log in won't work

Comment: What details are you talking about? Also, yes, the form does not work if the user is not logged in as I have provided a mixin.

Comment: add your mixin to the question